# JavaScript regexp \s* in not recognizing the new line character \n

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use new line character `\n` with the regexp `\s*`, but it is not breaking the line.

```js
var str = '  A B  C   D EF <br>';
var str1 = '  A B  C   D EF <br>';
var str2 = '  A B  C   D EF <br>';
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '#'); // ##A#B##C###D#EF#
str1 = str1.replace(/\s+/g, '#'); // #A#B#C#D#EF#
str2 = str2.replace(/\s*/g, '#');

console.log(str);
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `<br>` is not `\n`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline